# Windows browser which closes completely when it loses focus

Tags: windows, web-browser

When the [Android InBrowser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.tommie.inbrowser) loses focus, for instance by showing the home screen (desktop), it terminates its process. In addition, it issues “do not track” requests, uses HTTP, doesn’t keep a history and has a few more secure features up its sleeve.

Is there anything similar for Windows? Note, that it can’t have any “are you sure” or similar dialog boxes; just lose focus & it disappears completely, preferably with other security features.